# Unity4.7.2f1 Mac. Problemas con UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity3d, macos

Buenas,

Estoy intentando compilar un proyecto que tenemos en Unity para Mac, en Windows funciona perfectamente y podemos sacar el .apk correspondiente para Android, pero cuando tratamos de exportar el proyecto en xCode nos salta el siguiente mensaje:

> "Erro building Player: MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.SetBuildProperty'"

¿Alguna idea?

Un saludo.

Comment: Has cambiado los PlayerPref para que sea .ios en vez de .android?

Comment: Querras decir BuildSettings ¿no?. y aunque no los haya cambiado al construir la aplicación se cambia solo. @Flowen

Comment: Cómo estás intentando exportarlo a xCode?

Comment: @Flowen Desde Unity: File>Build Settings>Build